# Gradient of function in terms of retarded time produces time derivative

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation

In Griffith's introduction to electromagnetism on page 479, there is this following equation:

\begin{align*}
\nabla V &\cong \nabla \left[\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\boldsymbol{\hat r} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{p}}(t_0)}{rc} \right] \\
&\cong  \left[\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\boldsymbol{\hat r} \cdot \ddot{\mathbf{p}}(t_0)}{rc} \right] \nabla t_0 \\
&=  -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} \frac{[\boldsymbol{\hat r} \cdot \ddot{\mathbf{p}}(t_0)]}{r} \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}
\end{align*}

given that $t_0\equiv t - \dfrac{r}{c}$. Why is it that one the second line the dipole moment -- the  $p$ function -- gains an extra time derivative if the gradient is in terms of partial spatial derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t_0=t-r/c$ is a function of $r$, so the $\nabla$ acting on it is the same as $\partial_t$ (complicated a bit by signs and $c$).  It would be easier to see if he didn't use $t_0$, and put it all in terms of $(t-r/c)$ explicitly.

Comment: Ohh, I think I get it. Since we are working with retarded time, time then also becomes a function of $r$ and so the gradient acts on it.